# Error: Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and > Android-Gradle modules in one project

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have an IntelliJ 14.1.2 Project consisting of two modules - one is an Android Gradle based module and the other is a Spring Java-based module with Maven.

gps-trackman.v1 is my root project and I've not configured any outputs or facets for this project. The app is my android gradle module and I've configured Android and Android-Gradle Facet for this project and gps-trackman isn't my Spring Maven Project. I want to be able to build everything all together. Is it possible?

I now get this error message in my IntelliJ Eventlog

> Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported
>   for following modules: gps-trackman, gps-trackman.v1, app.
>   Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and
>   Android-Gradle modules in one project.
>
> The project 'gps-trackman.v1' is not a Gradle-based

Is this error just due to a misconfiguration of my project or is it really not possible to have a maven module and a Gradle module in one project?

Do I have to configure any Facets for the root project? Alternatively, do I have to convert my maven to gradle?

Comment: Are you opposed to converting the maven project to gradle?

Comment: Yes, then I've tried to convert the Maven project into a Gradle project, but that resulted in a bunch of other errors, so i would prefer to stay with Maven...

Comment: Alright, I just wanted to note that it is possible to add a regular java gradle project as a subproject to an android project.

Comment: Are the problems you're having described by JetBrains YouTrack ticket [IDEA-122904](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122904)? If so, do any of the workarounds listed in there help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Error "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 587):

1- close the project

2- close `Android Studio` IDE

3- delete the `.idea` directory

4- delete all `.iml` files

5- open `Android Studio` IDE and import the project

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

Comment: worked for me with just the deletion of .idea dir, on astudio 3.5

Comment: Does this work on only specific versions of Android Studio ?

Comment: Be careful deleting .idea directory. There is a lot of stuff in that directory that will get lost and not auto-generated when you relaunch A/S. Specifically `codeStyles` and `dictionaries`

Comment: It works for AS 3.6.3 too. I just closed the IDE, deleted the files and reopen. Didn't have to close the project nor import (I believe the IDE does it anyway).

Comment: @tir38, I think all the files in .idea folder are auto-generated. No need to worry while deleting. Android Studio creates every file by itself.

Comment: more precisely: deleting `modules.xml` from `.idea` directory works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813520/1529129

Comment: Received this after upgrading `firebase_crashlytics` package in a flutter project (Upgrade from Fabric-based to FB-based: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/crashlytics-sdk-now-available.html). This solution solved it.

Comment: It doesn't work on android artic fox, I think it's more related to Gradle but I don't find it...

Comment: Beware: deleting the `.idea` folder also removes shelved changes in Android Studio

Answer (score 122):

1. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
2. Close the project.
3. Go to project folder and delete .idea folder.
4. Delete YourProjectName.iml in project folder.
5. Delete app.iml in  app folder.
6. Open Android studio -> open existing project, and then select your
   project.
7. The Load Settings error and Unsupported modules detected error will
   be gone.

Comment: Thank. It helped me. And the solution is pretty! :)

But with:

Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: What are file will configure in .gitignore, can you please give suggestions for the new project.

Comment: 1.a After selecting "Invalidate Caches/Restart" a dialog appears. Make sure to choose the "invalidate" option only and close Android studio manually.  If you choose "invalidate + restart" Android studio will restart before you can complete steps 3-5.

Comment: @MohanRajS, all the files which generates automatically must be ignored. For example- every iml file, .idea folder, .gradle folder, build folder, .classpath, .project , .log, .apk, .aab etc.

Comment: Just invalidating caches and cleaning the project was enough for me.

Answer (score 87):

1. Close the project
2. Just **delete the modules.xml** in .idea folder.
3. Open the project again.

Comment: Worked for me with android studio 4.0

Comment: Worked for me too, needed to rebuild the project before it worked.

Comment: Damn..worked for me.. `cmd+shitf+.` to see hidden folders(.idea) in mac btw

Answer (score 46):

The ultimate solution to this error:

## **SOLUTION 1**

**Step 1** Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

**Step 2** Close the project.

**Step 3** Go to project folder and delete .idea folder.

**Step 4** Delete YourProjectName.iml in project folder.

**step 5** You will see a folder below graddle folder, Delete YourProjectName folder (it contains another YourProjectName.iml file).

**Step 6** Open Android studio -> open existing project, and then select your project.

**

## SOLUTION 2

**

**Step 1:** Open the Corrupted Project (The one showing error).

**Step 2:** Open system.gradle file.

**step 3:** add this line of code `include ':app'`.

**Step 4:** click on the sync, to sync the gradle file.

Comment: deleting .idea folder and .iml file helped.

Answer (score 24):

In my case settings.gradle contained invalid configuration.

I changed:

> ```
> include ':app'
> rootProject.name='<somthing else>'
> ```

To:

> ```
> include ':app'
> ```

Error is gone. So maybe check your settings.gradle for potential errors. If this won't work try to remove cache and other tips.

Comment: this was the only solution that worked for me! of course after invalidate caches and restart.

Answer (score 21):

First of all you should update to Android Studio Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77983

Then you should go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.

Then try to build the application again.

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

Comment: I don't use android studio .  this is not my case !

Comment: Was getting "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: mobile. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project" - this helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Tried all above. Didn't work.

Here's what worked. Go to the file called modules.xml

Delete all the modules there. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: It worked for me. I had this error on a *gradle* module that was later removed but error kept being reported no matter what. Removing the module from modules.xml worked while everything else didn't.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have added your module to the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':app'
include ':your-module'
```

Answer (score 8):

Press Ctrl-Alt-S > Uncheck "Android Support" plugin

(I wish I could tell you exactly why this works, but I can't. If you want to develop for Android, try using Android Studio, which is also made by Jetbrains.)

Comment: `File -> Settings (= STRG+ALT+S) -> Plugins -> uncheck "Android Support"` [JetBrains Help Page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000404920/comments/360000086479)

Comment: In my case I had no such a plugin, but had "Markdown plugin" marked as red incompatible, I uninstalled it and solved the problem after AS restart.

Comment: turning off the Markdown plugin allowed me to run https://invent.kde.org/network/kdeconnect-android . So can anyone explain why a dumb plugin for a text language would croak the entire build for a phone app??

Answer (score 7):

Had same issue with Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13.

I was able to solve it by following these steps:

- Go to the module settings and remove your module from the list
- Edit settings.gradle and remove your module from there also
- Physically move the module directory out of the project (to your desktop for instance)
- Then in the module settings again add a module and select as type 'Import Gradle Project' in which you select the module folder you have moved to your desktop (or anywhere else)

When you complete these steps the module will be copied into your project again, AS will start syncing Gradle again and that succeeds without errors :-) Check your GIT status and you will see as soon as you add your module directory to GIT again that nothing has changed to your working directory. So it's purely an issue with AS that gets somehow out-of-sync...

Based my solution on this comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008041#comment3

Answer (score 5):

This may be resolved by fixing `.idea/modules.xml`
Check for https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343944/11910757

Answer (score 5):

This happened when there are some cache issues.
Just remove .gradle,.idea and app/build folder.

Goto -> AndroidStudio -> File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart

This will open the same project again and Gradle will rebuild all files and caches. This will take around 10-12 minutes.
This will definitely be going to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me Android Studio 3.3.2.

1. Delete the .iml file from the project directory.
2. In android studio File->invalidate caches/restart.
3. Clean and Rebuild project if the auto build throws error.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, you can not delete the .idea folder

The best way is

- Delete all files inside of .idea
- Delete .idea

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps :

1-Command+Shift+F

2-Type : modules.xml

3-Open file

4-Remove those you get error for (the module when you get error once building project)

**Good luck :)**

Answer (score 3):

in my case it work by just invalidate and restart

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31103396)

Answer (score 2):

For me, my project was very corrupted. I don't know how I got into that state. What I observed was that several .gradle file and proguard file had a whole bundle of xml content. Fortunately, the physical file had the correct content in it, but android studio was displaying it as some xml file that looked like it belonged to some generated res xml data.  Things like "Sync to file system" or "sync project to gradle file", "invalidate cache and restart" or "gradlew clean" wouldn't clear up the issue.  I even replaced the bogus xml data being displayed in the gradle scripts with the original content, but that didn't help either. I tried some of the advise given above, but they either didn't work or seemed too complex for me to feel that me project would go back into a well formed state.

So I elected to create a new blank project.  Using file explorer, I copied all of the modules in the corrupted project into the new project (a plain old copy and paste)  I also replaced the "settings.gradle" and the root "build.gradle" files of the new file with the contents from the old file. Once that is done, you have to run "sync Project with gradle files and you're good to good.  If by chance your project root has some content that you physically added, you would have to copy that over too.

So that gets you back up and working. I don't know for sure what caused my project to get corrupted, but I think it might have to do with the laptop going into sleep mode.  My laptop was not allowing me wake up from sleep and the only way for me to wake up was to power off an power on again.  I did have some projects opened a few times when that happened.  So that's my best guess as to how the project might have gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

None of above worked for me but tried something random and it worked.

1. Copy the corrupted project directory.
2. Paste it at somewhere else.
3. Import it in Android Studio. (File-> New-> Import project)
4. And uncorrupted project get restored.

PS: You must have original corrupted project. (Means, copy it without tampering project structure)

Answer (score 2):

goto `.idea` folder open `modules.xml` file and see for yourself what module is there that you are not using in project currently.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply downgrade your gradle dependency to fit your current android studio version.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        ....
}
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution I found in this forum worked like a charm:

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory in the directory where your app resides

4- delete all .iml files in the directory where your app resides

5- open Android Studio IDE and import the project

Answer (score 1):

Copy the project files from the original source and paste it somewhere and then import from the Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Been dealing with this issue for a while every time I tried opening a project.

I always receive this error even though I knew I had not made any changes that should of caused this apart from exporting to zip.

To Fix:

- Make a new project or open project that works
- Go to file > open > "your project"
- Make sure your dummy project stays open.
  The project you were getting errors should be opened in a new window.

This fixed it for me without doing any changes or deleting anything.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works try Import **app folder not the Git root** while opening Android Project and Error will be gone

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory of the Project and re-open.

Answer (score 0):

***Writing in 2020*** -

If none of these worked, close **android studio** and then go to

> C:\Users\User.AndroidStudio(ANDROID_STUDIO_VERSION)\system and delete the **caches** folder

**Restart your project now**, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted all project from local Repos folder. Then Cloned new Project from `bitbucked` and imported it again, hopefully error gone.

Answer (score 0):

**Writing in 2023:**
try invalidate caches and restart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use firebase, this error can also occur when there is a mismatch between firebase Android package name and project package name.
Make sure firebase package name is same as namespace (you can find it here: /andriod/app/build.gradle)

Comment: It would be beneficial if you showed examples of the mismatch, and the correction, rather than just pointing to the gradle build script.

Answer (score -3):

the error explain all things, the idea is confused between **gradle** and **maven**.

try to create new project with two **gradle** modules, you can build spring application with gradle as maven.

see [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) example from spring guides

Comment: Please try to add solution instead redirecting to another websites

Answer (score -4):

Try to copy and paste from the project files

Comment: You need to provide somewhat more detail than that, such as _which_ project files (POMs? IntelliJ files? something else) to copy from, and which to copy to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31700267)