# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android project which is on below link

https://gitlab.com/vandy-aad-2/aad-2-assg-1/

```
Gradle sync is failing to give the error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0
```

Tried updating the SDK but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `google()` repo in the repos in the top level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same no change

Comment: @Vishalpatil Try to check if this link is available : https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/24.2.0/cardview-v7-24.2.0.pom

Comment: Hey. I am really new in Android so can i know where to paste or how to use this file

Comment: @Vishalpatil It is just a check to verify if the link is available. It is the link used by gradle to get this library.

Comment: Hey , I am really new in android so can you tell how to use the file i downloaded from your link.

Comment: This worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142056/error-unfortunately-you-cant-have-non-gradle-java-modules-and-android-gradle