# Shared Activity with Compose in Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a problem with setting up an activity that resides in shared code in a KMM project and uses Jetpack Compose. When the activity is in Android source *(/app)* this works fine. But I'd like to publish a shared *(/common)* library without any application.

As an example I forked a great minimal KMM+Compose project: https://github.com/cyberhenoch/PeopleInSpace :

- added the compose activity (SharedActivity) to the shared code
- updated the dependencies in shared code **androidMain**

It compiles fine but at runtime I get:

> Process: com.surrus.peopleinspace, PID: 4067
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **No static method setContent**$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/CompositionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
> in class Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super
> classes (declaration of
> 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in
> /data/app/com.surrus.peopleinspace-8P35Dcwzn9_G-xN9YdwFrA==/base.apk)
> at com.surrus.android.SharedActivity.onCreate(SharedActivity.kt:12)

I tried to add the options described here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#configure_gradle but

- not all can be added to the common module (kotlinOptions?)
- in the original project they are not required and it works perfectly good
- after adding several of them in different combinations it does not even compile (*exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/serialization/DescriptorSerializerPlugin
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)*)

What should I do to make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which platforms does you KMM module supports? Have you placed your activity under androidMain or commonMain? Under which task did this error come?

Comment: @Philip The example project supports quite a few platforms but here I am interested just in Android. Build succeeds and the error is happening during runtime after running the SharedActivity that is placed in androidMain. [link](https://github.com/cyberhenoch/PeopleInSpace/blob/main/common/src/androidMain/kotlin/com/surrus/android/SharedActivity.kt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change required is adding **org.jetbrains.compose** plugin.

Basing on IDEA (not Android Studio) template for creating multiplatform project with Compose
[Jetpack Compose for Desktop (Experimental) -> Mutiplatform uses Kotlin 1.4.30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm0hd.png)

Project build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

...

allprojects{
    ...
    maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev") }
}
```

Common module build.gradle.kts

```
plugins{
    ...
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "0.3.1"
}
```

Apart from that after adding the plugin Android Studio messed up the modules showing "no module selected" error and the issue described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142056/error-unfortunately-you-cant-have-non-gradle-java-modules-and-android-gradle). But opening it in IDEA showed an option to fix multimodule gradle project. I fixed it this way and reopened in Android Studio.

The changes required can be seen in [the example repo](https://github.com/cyberhenoch/PeopleInSpace/commit/341ae9f24d380763c4e7239953b1c61634aa7060).

*AS version 2020.3.1 Canary 15 & IDEA version Community 2021.1*

Thanks [John O'Reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793861/john-oreilly?tab=profile)!