# Android Studio - Issue while Cloning repository from GitHub

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am getting this error when I am cloning repository from GitHub to android studio.

`Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: GitHubTestV3. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.`

When i try to run the app i get this error

`Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?`

Any Solution for this?

I have tried invalidate cache & restart as suggested by other answers on stackoverflow but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Error "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

"**Sync Project With Gradle Files**" solved the problem for me.