# Unsupported Modules Detected: Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, ide, build.gradle

> Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for the following

> modules: MemorandamApp. Unfortunately, you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

This Error caused me to erase my files. Newly opened files and created files are affected by this problem.

Answer (score 45):

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory

4- delete all .iml files

5- open Android Studio IDE and import the project

The answer is taken from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 10):

Switch to project mode and go to .idea/modules.xml & delete the invalid/not existing path . Then File => Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Answer (score 2):

- Clear all cache
- Close the project
- delete .idea folder and .iml files
- Reopen the IDE and project