# How to fix React Native app error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have the following error when I try to run my React Native app in Android Studio.

When running the application, it tries to start, but fails and displays the following error.

```
07/26 15:05:47: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 API R.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.recetasdemiyaya/com.recetasdemiyaya.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 6259 on device 'Pixel_3_API_R [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/recetasdemiyay: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/recetasdemiyay: Unquickening 13 vdex files!
W/recetasdemiyay: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/recetasdemiyay: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.recetasdemiyaya, PID: 6259
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.recetasdemiyaya.MainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.recetasdemiyaya.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1885)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.recetasdemiyaya.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~CE-MOv3Jm55BXMcdUPlUeg==/com.recetasdemiyaya-889WixNrp2DNabkeMOGRLA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:49)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6521) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1885) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
```

In the EVENT LOG section, it shows me the following error:

> Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for
> following modules: lottie-react-native, react-native-admob,
> android-react-native-fbsdk, android-react-native-onesignal,
> android-react-native-fast-image, android-react-native-blur,
> android-react-native-webview, android-react-native-vector-icons,
> android-react-native-gesture-handler,
> android-react-native-linear-gradient, android-react-native-admob,
> android-lottie-react-native, react-native-blur, react-native-fbsdk,
> react-native-onesignal, react-native-gesture-handler,
> react-native-vector-icons, react-native-linear-gradient,
> react-native-fast-image, react-native-webview. Unfortunately you can't
> have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project

.

When I try to run the application in the terminal from the root of my project, with the `react-native run-android`   command, the application shows for an instant, but it doesn't start working, but it doesn't show me errors.

However, when I run the `react-native run-ios` command the application works perfectly in my simulator.

My experience is little and my command of English is also little, so I do not know where to go and where to look within my project to correct the errors that Android Studio shows me.

I have updated Android Studio, as I have read similar problems before coming to ask, but I don't know how to eliminate LA CACHES / RESTART => INVALIDATE CACHES & RESTART, which I have seen [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668252/android-studio-error-unsupported-modules-detected-compilation-is-not-supported)

What should I do for Invalidate Caches?

I'm still looking for a solution, but I can't find a way, I keep looking at other questions, but I think I'm not looking correctly, and that's why I'm here.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1- close the project

2- close Android Studio IDE

3- delete the .idea directory

4- delete all .iml files

5- open Android Studio IDE and import the project

if issue still exist copy project to other location and open it again in Android studio.

Comment: Thanks @BhanderPathania  , I've already followed your advice but it doesn't work. Now another error: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Expected org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult but found org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult`

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning gradlew works for me

`cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`